# How can I fix a div floating behind another div when it isn't meant to? (CSS included below)

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a very noob-ish website with the css rules below (nevermind the empty rules), but somehow the header seems to get behind the codrops-top navbar. This limits how I position the header and the rest of the content. Help me fix it (please!)

```
html, body {

    }



    #page-container {

    }

    #content {

    }

    .codrops-top {
        line-height: 24px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #262525;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-transform: uppercase;

        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


    }
    .codrops-top a {
        padding: 0px 20px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #f3f0f0;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codrops-top a:hover {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    }
    .codrops-top span.right{

    }
    .codrops-top span.right a{

        display: block;
    }

    .selected{
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    }

    .transparent-style{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        opacity: .4;
    }

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

Below are the HTML codes, it is a real mess but this is how I remember basic HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>28CUP2015 OPEN RECRUITMENT</title>
    </head>

    <link href="css/design.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="28cup, 28 cup, 28 cup 2015, mpkosis28, mpk osis 28, mpkosis, mpk osis" />

<body>
    <div id="page-container">
        <div class="codrops-top">
                <center>
                    <span>
                        <a href="index.php">
                        <strong>HOME</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href=about.php>
                        <strong>ABOUT</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="mailto:osisavartana@gmail.com">
                        <strong>CONTACT VIA E-MAIL</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://goo.gl/forms/oXBZKgpFzk">
                        <strong>INPUT ASPIRASI 28 CUP</strong>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </center>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
        <div class="header">
            <h3>LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>sdfwsdvchwdhcirhgtierguheriucyergchiwergciergfaefhoajrceac,asirf,weirc,isdfhoxweht,cowheoithciweticheish,icweiltc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's been a long time since I built a web page from the ground up, sorry if all that confused you guys.

Comment: Could you remove all the irrelevant code

Comment: @Nick I'll do that when I ask another question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative positions in CSS to position the div below the other. For Example;

```
#div1 {
    position: relative;
}

#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use absolute positioning on an element, you remove the element from the document flow. In other words, the elements around it act is if it's not there (in most cases). That's why everything is running over your header. Here's a codepen of your layout with absolute positioning commented out:

http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/iegqd

```
obligatory code:
/* position: absolute */
```

To better understand absolute positioning (and positioning in general), check out MDN's documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position